# Android JobScheduler setRequiresDeviceIdle

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

How exactly does the method "setRequireDeviceIdle" from JobInfo.Builder works? From what I understanded in Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiresDeviceIdle(boolean)) it should guarantee that your jobs only launches if there was no interaction with the device.

My experience it's different:

```
private void scheduleRestartJob(){
    ComponentName mServiceComponent = new ComponentName(this, RelaunchAppJobService.class);

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1002, mServiceComponent);
    builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true);
    builder.setPersisted(true);
    builder.setOverrideDeadline(10000);
    mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
```

If I quit my app, and start to use another one, it doesn't matter if I'm active or not, since the job will always run after the 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

> If I quit my app, and start to use another one, it doesn't matter if I'm active or not, since the job will always run after the 10 seconds.

That is because of this line:

```
builder.setOverrideDeadline(10000);
```

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setOverrideDeadline%28long%29):

> The job will be run by this deadline **even if other requirements are not met**

(emphasis added)

So, your job will run when the device goes idle or 10 seconds from now, whichever comes first. In all likelihood, the 10 seconds will elapse first.

Comment: Well that makes sense, but before using "setOverrideDeadline", i used "setPeriodic" with the same 10 seconds. However the behaviour was the same (despite the documentation doesn't refer for that one that it ignores the other requirements). What I'm trying to achieve here it's to relaunch my app if the user has been idle for a certain amount of time.

Comment: The reason you saw this behaviour using `setPeriodic` without `setOverrideDeadline` is that despite what the documentation says, `setPeriodic` seems to implicitly set an override deadline and ignore all the other requirements. It seems you can work around this bug by putting a an `if (!jobParameters.isOverrideDeadlineExpired())` check in your `onStartJob` method.